# Is there a way to use grid fill with the mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling

I would like to use gridfill on a circle, but I would also use the mirror modifier to keep symmetry. Is there a way to use gridfill on an object with mirror modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible only with some preparation.

[*GridFill*](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill) uses closed loop to work on and adjacent number of vertices. You can't use it if you have opened loop (ready to be mirrored). The *Mirror* modifier won't change anything as the geometry it creates doesn't exist unless the modifier is applied. So you are left with 2 general ways:

- Applying modifier temporarily

  1. Apply modifier, make necessary changes.
  2. Remove half of the mesh. It is ready to be mirrored again.
  3. Add modifier back.
- Create geometry necessary for *GridFill* manually.

  1. Select 2 vertices which are located on the mirror plane (those connected only to one edge).
  2. Create an edge (with <kbd>F</kbd>).
  3. Subdivide it. The number of subdivisions depends on number of the vertices of the rest of the mesh. In case of circle from 32 vertices, subdivide 7 times (so to create 7 additional vertices).
  4. Select all and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > *GridFill* (probably modifiy its settings a bit).

The half of the mesh will be filled with the quad topology reflected in the mirrored part.

[image]

Comment: Just make sure the "Merge" option is on in the Modifier.